# Allowing users to upload profile pictures but 1) form isn't valid 2) not saving correctly

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to allow users to upload profile pictures. I've done this by creating a File model, and adding a foreign key referring to a user. A user can upload many files. this is the model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class File(models.Model):
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='images/')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='files')
```

next, the form for the upload looks like this:

```
from django import forms
from .models import File


class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=File
        fields=('files',)
        widgets={'files':forms.FileInput(attrs={'id':'files','required':True,'multiple':True})}
```

finally, the view 'upload pics' is the following:

```
def upload_pics(request, user_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pics = form.save(commit=False)
            pics.user = request.user
            pics.files = request.Files['files']
            pics.save()
            return redirect(request, 'accounts:profile', user_id)

    else:
        form = FileForm()
        render(request, 'accounts/account_form.html', {'form':form})
    return render(request, 'accounts/account_form.html', {'form':form})
```

I'm running into two issues:

1. the form is not valid, even if I click on several pictures
2. the pictures aren't saving correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the files to the form.

```
form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Also, you don't show your template, but make sure you are using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: thanks Daniel! but my second issue is it's not saving, and its throwing me the error 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Files'. this error is being thrown when I am trying to save the files " pics.files = request.Files['files']' . but isn't  'files' being defined in the form's widgets above?

Comment: Well, first of all case is important, it should be FILES. But secondly there should be no need to save the files separately, saving the form will do that already.